# automated unit test case for iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

for last three days i am trying to create unit test case using OcUnit. but not succeed yet . every time i google i get new tutorial with different configuration. and apple tutorial is the only which worked in xcode 3.2.5 . plz if any one know step to create logic test as well as application test please let me know .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apple's approach forces you to make an artificial and unnecessary distinction between "logic tests" and "application tests". It also makes debugging a real pain.

For iOS unit testing, try [GTM](http://code.google.com/p/google-toolbox-for-mac/wiki/iPhoneUnitTesting) or [GHUnit](http://gabriel.github.com/gh-unit/) instead.

**Update:** Xcode 4 changes everything. I now use the built-in OCUnit for iOS unit tests. See [Xcode Unit Testing: The Good, the Bad, the Ugly](https://qualitycoding.org/xcode-unit-testing/)

Answer (score 2):

i use GHUnit, is a test framework for Objective-C, you can follow the instruction on the [GHUnit](http://gabriel.github.com/gh-unit/) page or see the video [TDD for iPhone Development](http://www.vimeo.com/16722907) , GHUnit it's easy to use and very helpful.

hope this help.